# BigData analysis: scalability but quick development

Tags: performance, algorithm, bigdata

Which do you consider is the best language to processing (getting statistical results) of analysing some GB of data information, taking into account these limitations:

- Open source code.
- Data can be analyzed in matrixes.
- Developing time limited.
- Cost of processing also limited.

For, example, Octave, Fortran, C++, C, Python, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whichever language you are most familiar with. All of those languages have very performant open source options for doing big-matrix math.

Answer (score 1):

I would look for Python with NumPy extensions.

Comment: I have seen this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322559/how-to-get-started-with-big-data-analysis?rq=1